# %d golang, how do you add spaces between Prints?

Tags: go

I have question related to golang verbs, especially **%d**. In this case I have **"%4d** " that I can't understand how does it prints the empty space that actually **reduces in size when printing bigger numbers** like in the last line with 2 digit numbers (3 empty spaces) and with 1 digit numbers where it prints 4 empty spaces?

```
for _, line := range s {
    for _, value := range line {
        fmt.Printf("%4d ", value)
    }
    fmt.Println()
}

$ go run main.go 5
   1    2    3    4    5
   2    4    6    8   10
   3    6    9   12   15
   4    8   12   16   20
   5   10   15   20   25
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the documentation for the `fmt` package states:

> For most values, width is the minimum number of runes to output, padding the formatted form with spaces if necessary.

In your case, it outputs a minimum of 4 runes, padding as necessary. %04d would pad with zeros.